# How to consume from an async Queue in a non-blocking way?

Tags: python, tornado, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a terminal like feature in a web application using tornado, websockets and `asyncio.Queue`

I am stuck now in implementing something like the `input` function where the coroutine pauses execution and waits till the user inputs something

My initial design was to create a session object for each user implementing a `send`, `receive` and `next` methods

- `send` method is used to send message to user
- `receive` method to receive user messages and redirect them to handlers
- `next` method to pause execution of handler until the next user message

Session class:

```
import asyncio

class Session:
    def __init__(self, ws_handler):
        self.ws_handler = ws_handler
        self.cbs = list()
        self.q = asyncio.Queue()
        self.waiting = False

    async def consume(self):
        return await self.q.get()

    async def next(self):
        self.waiting = True
        return await self.consume()

    def send(self, response):
        self.ws_handler.write_message(response.bytes())

    async def receive(self, msg):
        if self.waiting:
            await self.q.put(msg)
            self.waiting = False
            return
        await views.authenticate(self, msg)
        for cb in self.cbs:
            print('calling', cb.__name__)
            await cb(self, msg)

    def register(self, *callbackss):
        self.cbs += list(*callbackss)
```

and being dumb enough I thought I could use it like this:

```
async def handle_input(some_message):
    session.send("Please enter your name")
    name = await session.next()
    # do some stuff
```

This actually worked in a way that the `handle_input` was paused as expected but of course the whole server was blocked forever.

My question is how to properly use `àsyncio.Queue` or any other strategy to achieve the `input` like functionality

I am using python 3.6 and tornado 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** `asynctio.Queue` doesn't work with Tornado's event loop. That is why you're getting that *blocking* behaviour. See [the issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2214) I opened about this.

You've two choices now:

1. Use [`tornado.queues.Queue`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html) instead of `asyncio.Queue`.
2. Or use asyncio's event loop instead of Tornado's event loop. See [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html).